# Could not install app on device, react-native

Tags: node.js, android-studio, react-native, gradle, npm

I am extremely new to app development. I am facing the following error during the installation of my app on emulator by using the CLI:

Error Message on the Terminal:

[image]

Following are the details of my project:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.14.1-all.zip
```

I don't know what is causing this, and I have tried deleting the gradle (version 2.14.1) multiple times and zipping it again inside the 'gradle' folder. Still It does not seem to be resolved.

How can I solve the problem?

Comment: try with cleaning build

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same problem as yours! Because when I first run "react-native run-android", my INTERNET is SLOW and LAG, CORRUPTED. This bad internet connection lets to download a TEMPORARY DAMAGE file gradle....zip.

Solution: The gradle-2.14.1-all.zip was damaged,so it should be replaced with a new gradle-2.14.1-all.zip

Then go to android folder of your react native application

```
./gradlew clean
```

Try running the application again